# EF 6: Removing entities results in empty objects

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have a confusing situation occurring on my database.
For reasons I can't determine, whenever I remove an item from the DbSet held by my DbContext (called `DataRepository`), three more "empty" items of the same type are added.

Here's the code for my `Teacher` entity (it does inherit from `User`, and I use TPT inheritance to handle that).

```
public class Teacher
    : User
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }

    public Teacher()
    {
        Department = new Department();
        InternalBookings = new List<Booking>();
        Classes = new List<Class>();

        Access = AccessMode.Teacher;

        Title = string.Empty;
        Email = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Similarly, the `Department` entity.

```
public class Department
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

    public Department()
    {
        Teachers = new List<Teacher>();
        Rooms = new List<Room>();

        Name = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Edit: And the relevant parts of the `DataRepository` code:

```
public class DataRepository
    : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    public DataRepository()
        : base(@"data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + Path + ";Database=Data;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataRepository>());
    }
}
```

Then, in some testing code, I have:

```
using (DataRepository Repo = new DataRepository())
{
    Repo.Bookings.Remove(Repo.Bookings.Single(b => b.Id == 1));
    Repo.Teachers.Remove(Repo.Teachers.Single(t => t.FirstName == "R...."));
    Repo.Classes.Remove(Repo.Classes.Single(c => c.Owner == Repo.Teachers.FirstOrDefault(t => t.FirstName == "R....")));
    Repo.SaveChanges();
}
```

This simply removes one of the `Booking` entities in the Db, as well as the associated `Teacher` and `Class` (as a result, there are no orphaned entities in the Db).

The problem is that after running this code, the DbSet of `Department`s in the DbContext has **three extra, empty items**. I can put a breakpoint in the constructor of `Department` and see the new objects being created. From the call stack can infer that it's being created by an iterator, but surely that wouldn't add it to the database?

Another strange effect is that by using, say `Repo.Bookings.Remove(Repo.Bookings.ToList().Single(b => b.Id == 1))`, I end up with 7 new items instead.

I think I'm missing something very important here, so any help appreciated.

---

Solution was to remove all initialisations of entries in the constructors of other entries - List initialisations are ok, just not the entries themselves.

Comment: Try replace "Remove" with "Where"

Comment: @User2012384 I'm trying to Remove items from the database, not filter them.

Comment: @Moho Updated - I only omitted it originally as it's nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your empty constructor for `Teacher` creates a new `Department` with no name (hence the empty items). EF notices that "change" and saves it to the Departments table.

EF requires the parameterless constructor to create objects it wants to return from queries, but in your case simply creating those objects causes changes. The more objects it creates internally while performing queries, the more empty items you get in your table.

Comment: Thanks, it had never occurred to me that EF might be able to detect the new objects if they weren't explicitly added.

Comment: It's generally pretty good at tracking changes unless you tell it not to. It mainly falls over when the there is no explicit or conventional relationship between two objects, so you have to tidy up manually.

Answer (score 1):

Give me a few min to confirm but my money says instantiating a new Department in the Teacher constructor is a bad idea.

The Teacher object loads data from the database, runs the constructor and creates a new department every time.